# Get the pixels of a string

Tags: java, string, graphics, pixel

While doing some stuff with the `drawstring()` method, I was wondering if there was a way of to extract a pixel array from a string parameter, so that the return type could fit into a 2d pixel array?
The method also needs to work with sizing and coloring.

I have already managed to draw the string to a graphics parameter that has a pixel listener attached to it, using `drawstring()` and then simply getting the data from that specific area.
But I was wondering if their is a way to get the pixels without having to draw it?

I want to be able to add effects like waves, 3d rotations and cool particles effects using the pixel engine i have, so to draw and then grab the pixels takes to much update space!

And remember that the string will be scaled, colored and transformed before it is extracted to a pixel array, so drawing the string once wont work.

Comment: Drawing it IS getting the pixels from it - that's kind of what drawing does!

Comment: Pretty sure you have to draw it to get pixels. Depending on what you're actually using the pixels for, `TextMetrics` may get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i guess ill have to look pretty in-depth to figure out if it is 100% not possible without drawing it. The reason why i don't want to draw it, is because by drawing it, then copying the pixels that were just drawn, their is an unnecessary amount of script that is needed, i edited my question stating that i want to transform the pixels to do waves, 3d rotations using the pixel engine i have, which means that if their is a drawing and then grabbing of pixels for everytime this happens, the updates per second will drop lots.

Comment: HOW do you want to obtain the pixels? (I mean, in which form?) You can simply paint the string into a `BufferedImage`, and you'll have (more or less) direct access to an `int[]` storing the RGB pixel values. I can't imagine a shorter way than that. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The act of drawing a string is complex. The text data in the string first has to be decoded into a sequence of glyphs in a given font. These are then rasterized by intersecting lines with the font's curve definitions at the scale your are rendering it. (Actually, with a process called "hinting" this is even more complex.) Once you have rasterized the glyphs you have the array of pixels you can then send to the display device.

What you want to do is to interrupt this process in the middle by transforming the text into a set of curves which are created from the font glyphs. Code like the following will give you the curves:

```
Graphics graphics;
Font font = new Font("ComicSans", Font.PLAIN, 12);
GlyphVector vector = font.createGlyphVector(graphics.getFontMetrics(font).getFontRenderContext(), "Lorem ipsum");
Shape shape = vector.getOutline();
// transform shape
```